# Can't change theme on view in Drupal

Tags: views, theming

I have just create a view with a page as a display. There is a theme option under the advance setting. I change the theme and save the setting. However the theme I saw didn't change at all. Can anyone advise what went wrong? Actually, I look at the them option again, it didn't being saved even I have saved.

Comment: View is a lot more complex than other modules and doesn't allow to change themes on the same site. It's more for creating different blocks, menus, fields, you know the bulk of the appearance. But the last suggestion works perfectly Themekey worked perfectly! You can change themes for paths, pages or even mobile display! Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding what the theme link in the advanced section of views. It is meant to help themers choose the right template file, show which template file is being used and get quick access to the default template code.

In order to change the theme on a specific Drupal page, take a look at the [ThemeKey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module.